# How to get the current instance of MongoDB with C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb, instance, mongo-cxx-driver

I generate an object of the class mongocxx::instance in a constructor.

**constructor:**

```
mongocxx::instance instance{};
mongocxx::client client
{
    mongocxx::uri{}
};
database= client["test"];
```

Now I need to get this instance in a function. I tried this:

**function:**

```
mongocxx::instance::current();
database.drop();
```

My program crashes at the line `mongocxx::instance::current();`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your constructor ran to completion, the `mongocxx::instance` object that you had on the stack has been destroyed. You need to keep an instance of `instance` around that outlives the other types.

Please see the [instance management example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/examples/mongocxx/instance_management.cpp) in the sources for more examples of how to use this type.

Comment: Without the anonymous namespace this code works for me. I call the instance() method in different functions from objects of different classes. The Singleton object is created just once. But when I use the anonymous namespace like in the example, I get linking errors when I try to compile the code.